# EF Code First, specify relationship table?

Tags: ef-code-first

Classes:

```
public class Action
{
    public long ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users{ get; set; }
}


public class User
{
    public long ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Action> Actions{ get; set; }
}
```

Tables:

```
Actions 
| ID | Name |

Users  
|ID | Name |

ActionUsers 
| Action_ID | User_ID |
```

Note that `Action` and `User` has many-to-many relationship.

Assuming that EF can map the above example successfully (I simplified my original code), then I decided to do the following:

- rename the table `ActionUsers` to `Permissions`
- rename member of `Action` class, `Users` to `PermittedUsers`
- rename member of `User` class, `Actions` to `Permissions`

How would I tell the EF to use `Permissions` as relationship table instead of `ActionUsers` when mapping `User.Permissions` and `Action.PermittedUsers`? Can I achieve the desired configuration without using Fluent API?

Answer (score 2):

Using Fluent API :

```
public class Action
{
    public long ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> PermittedUsers{ get; set; }
}


public class User
{
    public long ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Action> Permissions{ get; set; }
}
```

you can simply override `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Action>().
      HasMany(c => c.PermittedUsers).
      WithMany(p => p.Permissions).
      Map(
       m =>
       {
         m.MapLeftKey("Action_ID");
         m.MapRightKey("User_ID");
         m.ToTable("Permissions");
       });
  }
```

if you want to have your own naming convention you can define `Permission` Table as a class :

```
public class Permissions
{

    [ForeignKey("Action")]
    public int Action_ID { get; set; }
    public Action Action { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

// context
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Action> Actions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permissions> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's what I did, is there any way I can achieve this without using Fluent API?

Comment: That's my problem, I do not know the DataAnnotations in this case. :) Is it possible then? I hope you can translate the codes to DataAnnotations, that would be a good introduction for me.